# SQL Server - VSS

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-sourcesafe

There is a great tool from RedGate called **SQL Server Source Control**. I liked it very much as it has seemless integration with the Source Control.

However, the pricing modal of this RedGate tool does not suit my purpose because it goes based on number of developers. I was looking for a one time buy without worrying about # of **number of developers**.

CodePlex, CodeProject are not of any help to find me such free product. Can anyone of you help me to find this kind of tool?

Again the purpose is ***seemless/tight integration with source control.***

I am sure there is someout out there who will help LOL

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/Database_CI.aspx